# Lumen 8 returns Bad Exception for GET actions with parameters

Tags: php, lumen

Im currently using Lumen 8. Im having issues with routing. The controllers work fine for get methods without parameters but I get a "Bad Routes exception" when I pass parameters

```
$router->get('/accounts', 'AccountsController@index');
$router->get('/accounts/{id:[\d]+}', 'AccountsController@show');
```

For example for the first route, localhost/accounts it displays the required data. The second route however when localhost:8002/accounts/1 it returns the error.

The routes are defined in an AccountsController

```
public function index(){
    $data = $this->collection(Account::all(), new AccountsTransformer());
    return response()->json($data);
}

public function show($id){
    try{
        return $this->item(Account::query()->findOrFail($id), new AccountsTransformer());
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
        response()->json(['error'=>['message'=>'Account not found']]);
    }
}
```